# jquery json parse - error on external file (same data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to parse a json file (using jquery). Working sample in:

http://jsfiddle.net/bw85zeea/

My problem is that When I try to load "data2" via external file, browser complains it's an invalid format.

```
var data2;
$.getJSON('dig.json')
.done(function (data) {
data2 = data;
});
```

The content in dig.json is:

```
[{"type":"Text","id":"f3e555e7-2a89-478c-a23c-feaabb454ef5","name":"Hello!","next":"ebc8dbcf-4847-4da1-bef9-e18bb016b630"},{"type":"Text","id":"ebc8dbcf-4847-4da1-bef9-e18bb016b630","name":"Miko Miko","next":"6ffb5ab3-b5fa-4d0e-8ca6-b7b8f01e0dfc"},{"type":"Text","id":"6ffb5ab3-b5fa-4d0e-8ca6-b7b8f01e0dfc","name":"End","next":null}]
```

Tried adding ' before and after, same result.

According to json validator it's ok. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Regards.

Comment: There must be something extraneous in the file. Check the Response section of the Network tab in Developer Tools/Firebug.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, unfortunately there are no lights in  the response section (loads ok) Still getting:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
json.html (línea 49, columna 8)

definitely something extraneous must be on file.

Comment: Is `dig.json` accessible from the Internet?

Comment: There wouldn't be an "lights", since the browser isn't parsing it, it's just raw data. But you should look there to see if there are extra characters before or after the JSON. Maybe a BOM character at the beginning of the file.

Comment: I can't find the character, it's accessible at:

http://estudio710.com/js/dig.json

Response seems ok (got my 3 objects)

Comment: I'm stumped, it sure seems to be valid. Are you sure it's pulling the correct file, check the access log on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server is sending the correct MIME type (**application/json**)

You can force this with PHP. For example, you can create a PHP script that sends the JSON file to the output with the correct MIME type like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

readfile('dig.json');

?>
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` ignores the content type and assumes it's JSON.

Answer (score 0):

i rewrote your code in a new fiddle.. you might wanna check this link here..

http://jsfiddle.net/qca6tmvb/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //var jsonString = '[{ name : "foo" }]';

    // JSON.parse not accepting placeholders so
    // i wrote the object inside instead

    var parsedJson = JSON.parse('[{ "name" : "foo" }]');

    //alert the value, the dom seems buggy
    alert(parsedJson[0].name);

    $.getJSON(parsedJson[0].name, function( data ) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: How does this help? His problem is only when he's getting the JSON from an external URL, not from a hard-coded JSON string.

Comment: Your `jsonString` is not valid JSON. In JSON, object keys have to be quoted.

Comment: yes sir Barmar i saw that. im working on the revise.. XD